# What is the best way to modify a class attribute (self) using an external/helper file (i.e. module) in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, flask, optimization

I have a `Flask` app that is getting really big and I would like to move some of the class functions to an external file as the file is exceeding 500 lines. These functions have some logic to modify some of the class attributes and are big (in terms of lines).

Below is a demo scenario where I am trying to keep a track of the number requests. Let us assume that `increment` is a huge function and I would like to move some of the functionality to a helper function i.e. `help_to_add` which requires some of the class attributes to be modified.

`app.py`

```
from flask import make_response
from modules import help_to_add
import sys

sys.path.append('..')
from untitled import app


class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        self.requests = 0

    def increment(self):
        self = help_to_add(self)


main = Main()


@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def hello():
    v1 = add(3, 5)
    main.increment()
    v2 = add(4, 6)
    main.increment()

    return make_response('{}, {}\n'.format(v1, v2), 200)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port='7000', host='0.0.0.0')
```

`modules.py`

```
def help_to_add(object):
    object.requests += 1
    return object
```

`_init_.py`

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
```

Right now I am achieving this by passing `self` as a parameter, but it does not look very clean to me. I am wondering if there is a better way to do this. I know that ideally we should have this function (`help_to_add`) in the same file under the class and I should try to move the static methods to a helper function and reorganize my code. I have done all of this, but I just have a lot of functions that need to read/modify class attributes and I have to move some of them to a separate module.

PS: Initially, I was using `global` variables and this file i.e `modules.py` acted as a file containing all the helper functions. I am trying to shift the entire code-base to use classes and avoid `global` variables completely.

Comment: To clarify, you essentially want a class definition that spans multiple files?

Comment: Yes, you could say that

Comment: Generally in Python, you don't do that. If you think a class is getting too big, you might evaluate why it's grown so large and what you can do with it, such as removing duplicate code and using multiple separate classes for different pieces of logic. But in Python, you don't split a class up across multiple files. You could, for starters however, put the class in its own file, separate from anything else, and that would be normal.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I was wondering if this is a good practice or not. Just to clarify, all the functions that require modification of attributes should belong to same class/file. If possible, all the functions requiring class attributes to read only (one time initialization) should also be a part of the same class, but there is no harm having them in a helper file. Static methods should be moved to a helper file to reduce file size. Is that right?

Comment: Those are probably more taste questions than anything. There's nothing inherently wrong with passing an argument to a function, but I'm of the opinion that if a function is acting on that "self" object a lot, it should probably be defined as part of that class, even if that makes for a larger life. That's really more of a style preference though. I'm inclined to prefer code live where it's intuitive to find, even if the file is larger as a result.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, if you *really* want to split code for one class across multiple files (which I wouldn't do myself), I don't see anything wrong with the pattern of:

```py
# In one file
from my_implementation import my_implementation

class Foo:
    def big_function_bar(self):
        my_implementation(self)

# In another file
def my_implementation(self):
    pass    # do stuff you need to do
```

This will work as expected. It may make things a bit messy, since you'll be jumping around files trying to find out what bit of code leads where.

On that note, you don't need to do:

```py
self = help_to_add(self)
```

Instead, you can simply do:

```py
help_to_add(self)
```

This is because objects are passed by reference in Python, so any changes you make to the `object` will be to that exact instance, not a copy of it.

Comment: The first half is exactly what I am doing now and mentioned in my question. However, the second part is useful. If it is pass by reference, then I don't have to return anything from the helper function as well. Thanks!